# Doxygen false warning for template notation

Tags: c++, doxygen

I do have a code fragment

```
vector<foo> bar;
```

It works fine, but Doxygen warns that " Unsupported xml/html tag <foo> found. Since it is a code, using escape characters, I found when googling,  is not possible. Can I suppress the warnings?

Comment: [tag:STL] doesn't refer to what you're thinking of.

Comment: Where do you have this? Is this actually in your source code, or is this in an example in your documentation?

Comment: @ Nicol Bolas "Since it is a code", in my eyes, means it is in my source code.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ I do not know what do you mean. I simple mean the STL notation, which confuses Doxygen

Comment: Please show a bit more code or elaborate, it is unclear what you try to do. Which version of doxygen are you using, when not the latest try to use the latest (1.8.11) and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
//! @cond DoNotRaiseWarning
code
//! @endcond
```